# Approximate the area under the curve $f(x) = x^2+4x+6$ on the interval $[2,6]$ using the right-hand Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Approximate the area under the curve $f(x) = x^2+4x+6$ on the interval $[2,6]$ using the right-hand Riemann sum where $P$ is the partition of $[2,6]$ determined by $\{2,4,5,6\}$

I set up the right Riemann sum $f(3)+f(4)+f(5)+f(6)$ but I don't understand what the partition or the values $\{2,4,5,6\}$ are used for.

Comment: I would assume that this is a typo, and that $\{3,4,5,6\}$ is what was meant (or $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$). Your plan of setting up that Riemann sum seems correct,

Comment: Or else you would use $2 f(4)+f(5)+f(6)$.